# Post Status is not updating from “Publish to Draft” and “Publish to Pending” in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type in which I am having a problem that its Post status always remains to Publish. Whenever I choose status draft or pending review and then click update button. It again shows post status as publish and doesn't change. Please see my code below and please tell me what I am getting wrong.

```
add_action('init', 'properties_create_post_type');

function properties_create_post_type() {

$soto_property_labels = array(
    'name' => __('Properties', 'custom'),
    'singular_name' => __('Property', 'custom'),
    'add_new' => __('Add New Property', 'custom'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Property', 'custom'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Property', 'custom'),
    'new_item' => __('New Property', 'custom'),
    'all_items' => __('All Properties', 'custom'),
    'view_item' => __('View Property', 'custom'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Property', 'custom'),
    'not_found' => __('No Properties found', 'custom'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Properties found in Trash', 'custom'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Properties', 'custom'),
);

register_post_type('soto_property',
    array(
        'labels' => $soto_property_labels,
        'supports' => array('title'),
        'public' => TRUE,
        'has_archive' => TRUE,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => __('properties', 'custom')),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url('properties/assets/img/properties.png'),
        'menu_position' => 42,
        'categories' => array(),
    )
); 
}
```

Comment: I found my answer on this URL-

 http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180253/how-to-update-post-status-using-meta-data-in-custom-post-type/180272#180272

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on my website and i don't see any problem, i can set the post status to whatever i want and update it correctly. therefore there is no problem with your code rather with something else.

do you get any error in the developer tools while pressing the update button ? have you checked your server log files for errors ?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

1. Create a post i.e. property
2. Click `Save Draft`[image: see the image]
3. If you published, `Save Draft` menu will be disappeared and `Update` button will be displayed.
4. Then if you want to change the `Draft` or `Pending Review`, click on `edit` right the dropdown of `status`. Select `Draft` or `Pending Review` from the dropdown. Click ok and `Update`.
5. Then `Save Draft` or `Save as Pending` button will be appeared in the place of image (what I have attached here with red circle).
6. Then click on `Save Draft` or `Save as Pending` button.

This is the way to `Update` any post as `Draft` or `Pending Review` once you have published. However, let me know if you did get yet, I'll send more screenshot.